# Can I restore the SVN repository from the copy of the repository folder on the server?

Tags: database-restore

The guy responsible for maintaining the SVN server was not having knowledge about the SVN server. Whenever he was told to take the backup of repository, He was just copying the folder of the repository from the server. He never took the backup using backup option in TortoiseSvn. Now the server is crashed. Is it possible to restore the repository from the copy of repository folder. This copy have the .svn folder as well. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. cd to backup folder
2. svn history

If this command shows you, history of the svn, you may be good to go.
The problem with using backup of the folders is that copy operation is not aware of svn mechanics.
If any operations was done on the repository while you are making backup, your backup may be broken, [Repository Backup TortoiseSvn](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository-backup.html).
If you are lucky, no operations was done while he finished backup and you are good to go.